# How to make python sympy raise an exception when evaluates or returns Infinity?

Tags: python, exception, sympy

I'm using sympy python library in order to get differentials, integrals, and functions evaluation. However, when it comes to certain cases like division by 0, naturally some cases will evaluate Infinity or some will just fail.

I've seen `Infinity` and `NaN` obtained in such error prone situations. I want to make sympy automatically raise an exception when it deals with such.

Basically I evaluate in two different states, one very simple:

```
fp = fx.subs(x,p)
```

Where `fx` is a symbolic expression (`fx=S(fx)`) and `p` a float.

Also I evaluate in this syntax like statements:

```
for x_i in xs:
    ys.append(float(fx.subs(x,x_i)))
```

Where `xs` and `ys` are lists and so `x_i` is a float.

In first statement raising an expception would come after evaluating obtained value, and so in second case. But how to avoid doing this manually? I think is better to set sympy or python environment to *treat* `Infinity` or `NaN` especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear what you are asking, but you can check if an expression has an infinity with `expr.has(oo, -oo, zoo, nan)`.

Comment: Well, I wanted exactly what your answer gives

Comment: What would zoo stand for?

Comment: `zoo` is complex infinity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_infinity#Complex_analysis. Recent versions of SymPy give `zoo` for `1/0`.